# Some python module to fetch chrome url

Tags: python, linux, package, pywinauto

I am building a python script that needs me to fetch the url of the active tab in Chrome(even if its running in the background). I am able to accomplish this using pywinauto on windows. Is there any similar module that I can use to get the same functionality on linux?

My pywinauto code:

```
from pywinauto import Application

app = Application(backend='uia')
app.connect(title_re=".*Chrome.*")
dlg = app.top_window()
url = dlg.child_window(title="Address and search bar", control_type="Edit").get_value()
url = "https://" + url
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate are they similar to Selenium? because Selenium was not really helpful in my case.

Comment: pywinauto's branch `atspi` should work on Linux, but it's not released yet. So you can try it and report any issue on GitHub.